# Unable to reset Skype password using Gmail "plus" address

Tags: gmail, account-management, account-recovery, skype-for-web

I recently signed up for Skype, and unfortunately, have forgotten my password. I went to reset my password with their online form, where it asked for the email address I signed up with. When I signed up, I used a Gmail "plus" address (username+skype@gmail.com), which the signup form did not complain about, and which they happily sent an automated email to.

The initial stage of the reset form doesn't complain either, but on the page after I click submit (where it should be sending me the reset code) it says that the email address is invalid. I haven't been able to find any information on how to get this to work.

Does anybody know of a way for me to reset my Skype password when my email address seems to be broken in their system?

I've never purchased any services from them, so their alternate method of providing your email address and billing records won't work.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Skype?

Comment: I have not yet; I plan to do that tomorrow. I was wondering if anybody had previous experience with this problem though so I could potentially solve it without having to hassle them.

Comment: After contacting Skype, they essentially told me they would be unable to help me because they don't really care. Not very good customer service, but apparently there's nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Skype has updated their system, and it finally let me reset my password recently when I went back to check (they never emailed me back). It's possible the problems will return eventually, so I changed my email address with them to one without the `+`.

Answer (score 2):

I run into many sites that dislike + in the email address (though never one that accepts it at first and then rejects it later). Workaround: get a spamgourmet account that forwards to your gmail account. spamgourmet.com lets you create "+"-style addresses without actually using plus signs (like webapps.barrycarter@spamgourmet.com)